# Selectively concatenating all the element values of subnodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML with the following structure

```
   <Group>
     <Note/>
     <Type>Anaerobic</Type>
   </Group>
   <Group>
     <Note>Note B</Note>
     <Type>Type B</Type>
   </Group>
   <Group>
     <Note>Note C</Note>
     <Type>Type C</Type>
   </Group>
   <Group>
     <Note>Note D</Note>
     <Type>Type D</Type>
   </Group>
```

I need to selectively merge the contents of the nodes into a single element as follows.

```
<Group_Note> Note B Type B , Note c Type C , Note D Type D</Group_Note>
```

As you can see the `<Type>` with the value 'Anaerobic' has not been concatenated along with the rest. I am able to get all the values into a single string using the following code.

```
<xsl:template name="Group">
      <xsl:for-each select="$thisNode//node()">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      <xsl:if test="self::text()">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I selectively pick and chose the nodes to concatenate. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the omission of 'Anaerobic' a bug you are trying to fix, or the requirement you are trying to meet and the reason you're not just using `string()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility to achieve this is using the following XSLT which iterates over non-empty `Note` elements and selects all their descending `text()` nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/root">    <!-- choose whatever root element you have -->
    <Group_Note>
      <xsl:for-each select="Group/*[../Note/text() != '']">
        <xsl:value-of select=".//text()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">  <!-- no space after last element -->
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Group_Note>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Group_Note>Note B Type B Note C Type C Note D Type D</Group_Note>
```

If you insert

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(Group[Note='']/Type,' ')" />
```

before `<xsl:for-each select="Group/*[../Note/text() != '']">`, you will get the `Anaerobic`'s `Type` attribute at the beginning - before accumulating the other `text()` nodes.

Note that I discriminated the `Anaerobic` node from the others by checking for an empty `<Note />`. If your requirements are different, you would have to adjust the predicates.

The final result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Group_Note>Anaerobic Note B Type B Note C Type C Note D Type D</Group_Note>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. How do i Modify it so that while concatenating I contenate with  Anerobic being first? for example if Anaerobic is at the last ?                                               <Group>
     <Note/>
     <Type>NoteA</Type>
   </Group>
   <Group>
     <Note>Note B</Note>
     <Type>Type B</Type>
   </Group>
   <Group>
     <Note>Note C</Note>
     <Type>Type C</Type>
   </Group>
   <Group>
     <Note>Note D</Note>
     <Type>Anaerobic</Type>
   </Group>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/*"> 
  <Group_Note>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Group"/>
  </Group_Note>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Group"/>

<xsl:template match="Group[Note != '' and Type != '']">
  <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::Group[Note != '' 
                and Type != '']">,</xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(Note, ' ', Type)" />
</xsl:template>
```